# how do I enable execution of enhancedSwitch statements in java 12?

Tags: java

i trying to run simple code to assign values through enhanced switch in java 12 version.

```
   int day;
    
    String nameOfDay = switch(day){     // using Enhanced switch to assign values
    
        case 1 -> "Monday";
        case 2 -> "tuesday";
        case 3 -> "wednesday";
        case 4 -> "thurday";
        case 5 -> "friday";
        case 6 -> "saturday";
        case 7 -> "sunday";
        
    };
```

getting an error:

EnhancedSwitch.java:8: error: switch expressions are a preview feature and are disabled by default.

```
            String nameOfDay = switch(day){         // using Enhanced switch to assign values
                               ^
```

(use --enable-preview to enable switch expressions)

EnhancedSwitch.java:10: error: switch rules are a preview feature and are disabled by default.

```
                    case 1 -> "Monday";
                           ^
```

(use --enable-preview to enable switch rules)

2 errors

please tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: The error tells you exactly what you need to do, which is pass the `--enable-preview` switch when compiling the code (and when running the code).

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/preview-language-and-vm-features.html for a description of what a preview feature is

Comment: thanks @Slaw , i should have searched a bit.